# Show $\sum \frac{3^{2k+1}}{k^{2k}}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm pretty certain it can be shown using the ratio test; I simplified $a_k+1/a_k$ to $[ 9(k)^{2k} )/( (k+1)^{2k+2} ]$ then let lim k->inf a_k+1/a_k = x thus lnx = lim k->inf ln[ 9(k)^(2k) )/( (k+1)^(2k+2) ] which I can't show diverges to -inf, as wolframalpha states.

Answer (score 4):

$$0\leq a_k=\frac{3^{2k+1}}{k^{2k}}=3\left(\frac{3}{k}\right)^{2k}\leq3\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{2k}=b_k\quad,\quad k\geq4$$
and the geometric series $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k$ is convergent.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}=\frac{9\cdot k^{2k}}{(k+1)^{2k+2}}\lt\frac{9\cdot k^{2k}}{k^{2k+2}}=\frac9{k^2}\to0$$